# Can Qt call two slots simultaneously, if they get called from the same signal?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt4, signals-slots

If there are two slots in two different threads and these slots are connected to a signal in a third thread. Can it happen, that both slots get called at the same time by the signal or do they get called synchronized every time?

I ask because i want to send some callback data structure (encapsulated with `QSharedPointer`) and ask if locking mechanism inside is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/threads.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) (official Qt documentation for Qt's signal/slot mechanism regarding threads).

Each slot is called inside its thread, therefore I am pretty sure anything can happen. You should install a lock mechanism.

Comment: The lock is already implemented :) but i have discovered that with a slot that blocks forever, emitting a signal to this slot and calling QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents() also blocks forever. Even if signal and slot are in two different threads (using auto/queued connection). Therefor i believe that all the slot calls from one thread are synchronized when it comes down to the actual event processing. But maybe the effect happened because of the slot living in the main app thread. Hoped someone already looked into relevant parts of qt source code and know for sure whats happening.

Comment: Are you sure that your QObject lives in different thread (it's not a QThread). Show us some code that creates your "different thread slots"

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to lock the actual signal/slot calls if you're using a Qt::QueuedConnection to pass the information to your threads, as the QueuedConnection mechanism handles this in a thread-safe manner.

That being said, you still need to protect any shared memory your threads access, regardless of how they were called.  The fact that a third thread emitted a single signal to cause both slots to be called will not change this.